# Documentation for Cocoapods

Tags: cocoapods, podspec

I'm writing **pod** for the first time. I need to add documentation but I didn't find way.

I found Jazzy. Generated doc looks like small website.

What I should do next ? 
Where I should put it ?

P.S. [This link where I should have doc](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/PiwikPROSDK/1.0.1)

Comment: watch this >> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oZSZ8mievUU

Comment: Cool! Thx @UdayBabariya!